# dependency inject in to an automapper resolver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, automapper, spring.net

I am working with AutoMapper in my c# mvc4 application. I use it to map my DTO objects to my view models.

I have created a custom resolver to resolve a particular property of the DTO to the Model property.

I am also working with spring.net dependency injection and I am wondering is it possible to inject directly in to my custom resolver?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as part of the AutoMapper configuration like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(ObjectFactory.GetInstance);
});
```

This example is for StructureMap, but the parameter is `Func<Type, object>` so I am sure there is something in Spring.net that can do a similar job.